# SQL Server Database recovery from corrupt database

Tags: sql-server

Last week I backed up my SQL Server by using Backup Exec 2012. I named the file "SQL Server BAK" which contained copies of my SQL Server databases. A few days ago I lost some part of my data due to accidental deletion. I backed it up, so I tried to restore the database from the .bkf file. The problem comes here, when I try to to restore my .bkf file, it becomes inaccessible.

Does anyone know what causes this? I'm suspecting corruption here (it's just a suspicion as I'm not sure). Please help me. The copies of my databases are very crucial.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're running the restore with the `NO RECOVERY` option. This will restore your database, but will leave it in the `RECOVERY` state.

You can easily check this by taking a look at it in the SSMS. It should say something like: `yourDatabaseName (Recovering...)`

If you haven't the option to take a look in your SSMS, you can simply querying your master database (if your restore doesn't aim at your master database at all. :-D).

```
SELECT name, state_desc
FROM sys.databases
```

You can filter it by `name` for example. Take a look at the column `state_desc` it should say something like `RECOVERING`.

If this is the case and your restore is successfully. You can simply run this:

```
RESTORE DATABASE yourDatabase WITH RECOVERY
```

This will immediately remove the `RECOVERING` state from your database and set it back to `ONLINE`.

**Behind the scenes:**

`RECOVERING` is just a transition state from (for example) `RESTORING` to `ONLINE`. In most cases a restore using `WITH RECOVERY` is good enough to set the database back online after the successful restore. But in some cases (e.g. Mirroring) you need to restore a copy of a database on a different machine and leave it in the `RECOVERING` state to define it as the mirroring partner for your `PRINCIPAL` database.

Comment: ...or if after the full backup is restored you want to restore log backups, you'd also want to start with NORECOVERY until you have applied the last log backup.

Comment: Well if you want them to be applied. If something is broken due to the last transactions, you probably just want a restore to retrieve a particular table or row. This way, you want the restore to be immediately online (if you restored it under a new name). As already said, it depends on the use case. :-)

Comment: Right, that's why I said "if...you want to..." - just wanted other readers to understand that WITH RECOVERY is not necessarily the option they want.

Comment: I didn't get you wrong. I know that you just wanted to mention it. :-) Should it be moved to the answer as it may be unclear? I thought I have described it clear enough. But if it's unclear I can move it to the answer.